# На канве пытаюсь вывести кнопку

Tags: android, canvas, button

Ошибка:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.sapeg.chess, PID: 21296
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.layout(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference

Куски кода:

```
public class chess extends Activity {
     Button mB, bt;
LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));
....
        class DrawView extends View {
        Paint p, paint;
        Rect rect;
    }

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            rect = new Rect();
        }
.....
      @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                 Button mButton,b;
                b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
               // invalidate();

                b.layout(11, 11, 11, 11);
                b.draw(canvas);
    //далее идёт прорисовка доски

main.xml:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ....обновил....Компилирует нормально, но при запуске выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Вы не можете получить объект из разметки методом `findViewById()` в методе `onDraw()`. В Java имена классов принято писать с Большой буквы

Answer (score 2):

Все View в Android ищутся в методе onCreate.

Попробуйте так:

```
public class chess extends Activity {
Button mB, bt, mButton,b;
LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
....

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
       // invalidate();

        b.layout(11, 11, 11, 11);
        b.draw(canvas);
```

Право говоря у меня нет перегрузки метода onDraw в классе-потомке Activity...

Comment: На самом деле `View` через `findViewById()` можно получить в любом методе активити, а не только `onCreate()`. Метод  `onDraw()` не принадлежит активити, поэтому там и нельзя получить объект кнопки из разметки через `findViewById()`

Comment: Согласен, просто onCreate() вызывается первым.

Comment: Если я собираюсь отобразить просто кнопку в Activity то, таким образом она отображается конечно, но самое главное, как на этом же экране и canvas отобразить? Либо можно выделить область, например прямоугольником и при "тап(е)" по его области перейти к другой активити?

Comment: @sapeg попробуйте после изменения View методом `View.draw()` вызвать метод `View.requestLayout()`. Учтите также, что метод `View.draw()` должен вызываться только после полной загрузки View и всех ее дочерних элементов.

Comment: @sapeg Если Вам необходимо лишь сменить `background` кнопки, то Вы можете использовать для этого `drawable` ресурсы. Там Вы можете описать любое оформление кнопки.

Comment: @sapeg Кстати, в методе `onDraw()` Вы не забыли вызвать конструктор суперкласса — `super.onDraw(canvas)` ??

Comment: Много всего. Буду разбираться.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200537/ghost
super.onDraw(canvas) не помогает.
  Чтобы проверить "полную загрузку View и всех ее дочерних элементов" нужен обработчик событий?

Comment: Нет, обработчик не нужен. Если Вы не уверены в том, все ли элементы загрузились, можете в `Activity` переопределить также метод `onPostCreate()` — он вызывается после метода `onCreate()`, в котором вызывается метод `setContentView()` и загружаются все элементы. Почитайте про жизненный цикл [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=ru) и еще вот это [Implementing a Custom View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html?hl=ru)

Comment: Ок. Почитаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А вообще, в данной ситуации, правильнее будет создать свое View расширяющее класс `Button` и в `onDraw()` описать все необходимые преобразования, например так:

```
public class MyButtonClass extends Button {
    public MyButtonClass(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Тут можно задать Вашей View параметры по умолчанию, например:
        this.setText("My Green Button...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        // Тут описываем все, что хотим сделать с View

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

В методе `onCreate()`, в свою очередь, пишем следующее:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout grouplayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.grouplayout);
    MyButtonClass myBtn = new MyButtonClass(this);
    grouplayout.addView(myBtn);
}
```

Comment: Всё это очень интересно, но кнопка в моём случае не самое главное, а "камень преткновения". Идея в том, что я нарисовал на канве шахматную доску и мне нужна ещё и кнопка к которой я собираюсь прикрутить обработчик событий, но кнопку на канве пока не получается вывести.

Comment: То, что я написал, реализовать совсем не сложно, и это работает. Попробуйте — надо лишь скопировать код.

Comment: Ok. Буду у себя попробую.

Comment: Если можно поподробнее: что есть R.id.grouplayout.
  Ваше предложение я реализовал, но кроме кнопки, шахматную доску на канве не выводит.

Comment: @sapeg `R.id.grouplayout` — это ID родительского (parent) слоя, наследуемого от [`android.view.ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (например, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`), в котором необходимо расположить ваше `View` (в данном случае `Button`). Опишите, пожалуйста, как у Вас реализована шахматная доска.

Comment: С помощью цикла for. Цикл заполнял черными и белыми квадратами.

Comment: @sapeg А квадраты что из себя представляют?? Каждый квадрат — это View??

Comment: Это изображение bitmap (png)

Comment: Как размечен layout доски?? В чем Вы пытаетесь нарисовать эти квадратики?? В каком-то View??

Comment: никак не размечена - это канва во весь экран.

Comment: Добавил код. Рисую просто на канве.

Comment: Нет квадраты это не bitmap. Я их реализовал методом drawRect. Bitmap это уже шахматные фигуры. (уже путаться начинаю).

Comment: Вы не можете рисовать на воздухе. Необходимо рисовать на каком-то View. Я не увидел, где Вы выложили код — ничего нового в Вашем первом сообщении не появилось. Думаю Вы рано решили писать игру под android, сначала стоит разобраться, как тут все устроено. Почитайте эту статью [StartAndroid - Рисование. Доступ к Canvas](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html) — вероятнее всего, Вы ее уже читали, но не до конца разобрались в материале статьи. Большинство интересующих Вас вопросов уже описаны в интернете и не один раз. Пользуйтесь поиском. ;)

Comment: Я действительно новичок в jave. Постоянно пользуюсь поиском. Ту статью уже не раз читал. Спасибо за советы. Буду искать дальше.

Comment: @sapeg На самом деле, все гораздо проще, чем Вы думаете, нужно только понять принцип. И всегда помнить, что **нет ничего невозможного**.